# Strange slow down when using struct and loop in Julia

Tags: julia

I made a speed-comparison between two functions with and without using struct as below, and its performance difference is huge: 0.07899 vs 0.0011 [sec]. The strange thing is that the contents of idxset in `test1()` and `test2()` are exactly the same(1...10000) but the processing time of the loop over those two are different. Note that the measurements were performed only for loops.

Could you explain how to improve my code with struct and why this happens?

```
struct Data
    bool
end
function test1()
    N = 10^5
    data = Data(trues(N))
    idxset = findall(data.bool)

    s=0.0
    @time for i in idxset
        s += i^2
    end
    return s
end

function test2()
    N = 10^5
    bool = trues(N)
    idxset = findall(bool)

    s=0.0
    @time for i in idxset
        s += i^2
    end
    return s
end
test1()
test2()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct Data
    bool
end
```

doesn't have any type information on bool, so `data.bool` cannot infer the type, leading to uninferred types in your function and slow code. `data.bool` being uninferred probably makes `idxset` uninferred which makes each `i` uninferred and slows down the arithmetic. Check this with `@code_warntype`. Fix this with:

```
struct Data
    bool::BitArray{1}
end
```

Comment: Alternatively `struct Data{T} bool::T end` if you don't bother to figure out the exact type (`BitArray{1}`) manually and/or to keep `Data` generic.